# Does British Airways allow the use of KneeDefenders?

Tags: air-travel, airlines, etiquette, united-airlines, british-airways

Yesterday a United Flight from Newark to Denver was forced to divert to Chicago's O'Hare airport after a fight broke out between two passengers over the use of a knee defender.

Does anyone know if this is acceptable with British airways?

Comment: I disagree with the edits done to this question. The title is asking about the product, but if you read the body now, it is either asking if the fight is acceptable, or a diversion.

Comment: @Darren maybe they will modify the airport scanners :D OR TSA will frisk you for them ..

Answer (score 2):

British Airways was asked (admittedly a while back), and while they don't ban it, they did say it was:

> "not something we would actively encourage"

[(source)](http://www.travelmole.com/news_feature.php?news_id=99176&c=setreg&region=4)

I haven't seen a more recent source yet :/